# Best way to get questions based on condition like StackOverflow

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting, pagination, sql-order-by

When I go to URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes, StackOverflow returns list of questions order by votes. I know how to implement this functionality but I'm looking for "the best way". I'll describe some ways and their cons.

1. Just use `order by`, `limit`, `offset` (for pagination). Cons: slow if number of rows is big.
2. Create index for `votes` column, and use `order by`, `limit`, `offset`. Cons: `votes` may be changed frequently, every time a row is updated, it'll be re-indexed. `limit` and `offset` still slow down if number of rows is big.

**More discussion**: if sorting functionality doesn't depend on `votes` only, but other columns such as `creationDate`, `numberOfViews`..., both ways above aren't good.

First way is very slow, every time client get list of ordered questions, function `f(votes, creationDate, numberOfViews)` is calculated for every row, then be order by, then apply panigation, very slow!

Second way is not good too, because `votes`, `numberOfViews` are changed frequently and I need to create an additional column `fValue` to store result of pre-calculated `f(votes, creationDate, numberOfViews)`. I need to update this column every time `votes` or `numberOfViews` are changed. Besides, if in future function `f` will be changed, it's terrible thing!

I'm looking for the best way to deal with these problems and I hope someone can help me.

**UPDATE**:

Schema looks like this:

```
Question (
    id: int primary key auto_increment,
    votes: int default 0,
    creationDate: timestamp default current_timestamp,
    numberOfViews: int default 0
)
```

Select list of questions:

```
select *
from Question
order by votes
limit index, 100
```

If sorting functionality based on other columns:

```
select *
from Question
order by votes + numberOfViews * 0.96
limit index, 100
```

or create new column `fValue = votes + numberOfViews * 0.96`

```
select *
from Question
order by fValue
limit index, 100
```

Comment: Why downvotes? Please discuss here with some information!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you need to provide more details. Your question cannot be answered in a general sense. Show query, schema, data, usage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a suitable INDEX -- Yes.  Use OFFSET -- No.

Instead, remember "where you left off".  Discussion of the problem and solution:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: I've read this discussion. But that problem order by only simple column, my order by condition is more complex.